# num_rows not working in Object Oriented method

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysql-num-rows, object-oriented-database

I'm a beginner in php & mysql. The `num_rows` is not working in the below **basic** example.
The whole script is inspired by the example in **w3schools**.
[w3schools example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp).

the browser shows an error message as follows.

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\test3\index.php on line 17

### code

```
<?php
require 'connect.inc.php';
require 'core.inc.php';

//check username & password is set.

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['psw'])) 
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['psw'];
    $pass_md5 = md5($password);
    if(!empty($username) && !empty($password))
    {
        $queryy = "SELECT ID FROM user WHERE email= $username AND password= $pass_md5";
        $result = $conn->query($queryy);

        echo $result->num_rows; //<---------------NOT WORKING..! -----<<
    }
    else echo "incorrect username-password combination";
}
?>

<html>
<form action="<?php echo $current_file ?>" method="POST">
    User name: <input type="text" name="username">
    password: <input type="password" name="psw">
    <input type="submit" value="Login"><br>
</form>
<html>
```

where `connect.inc.php` has some simple codes to connect to localhost and database. it's as follows:

```
<?php
//this sript connects to DB->mytest.

$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$dbname="mytest";

//create connection
@$conn=new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

//check connection
if($conn->connect_error)
{
    die("connection faild");
}
?>
```

and, `core.inc.php` is returns the current file location. it's as follows:

```
<?php
$current_file = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
?>
```

please help..

Comment: That's because you're not treating your query's variables as strings, which is part of the problem. Here http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php use that.

Comment: Move `//<---------------NOT WORKING..! -----<<` next to `$queryy = "SELECT ID FROM user WHERE email= $username AND password= $pass_md5";` in your question. That's where the ***real*** problem is. Using MD5, *tsk tsk*. So old and unsafe. I hope you're not planning on going LIVE with this.

Comment: I ***strongly*** suggest you read [@deceze](http://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze)'s excellent blog article [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're not quoting the strings in your query:

```
$queryy = "SELECT ID FROM user WHERE email= '$username' AND password= '$pass_md5'";
```

However, it would be best to use a prepared query and `bind_param` instead of substituting variables.

```
$queryy = "SELECT ID FROM user where email = ? AND password = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($queryy);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $pass_md5);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
echo $stmt->num_rows;
```

Comment: Maybe a quick mention about MD5? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `$conn` is not properly connected to your database or it doesn't have the required permissions to run a/the query. Or your query is invalid.

**Edit:**
Your query is missing `'`:

```
$queryy = "SELECT ID FROM user WHERE email= '$username' AND password= '$pass_md5'"
```

Comment: `$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;` is valid. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: Edited my answer. Sorry... I was elsewhere... :D

Comment: *"It looks like your $conn is not properly connected to your database"* - Seems fine to me. Other than the fact they're using `@` symbols which is an error suppressor, the connection should work if there are no errors.